# It seem that the textbook "Machine Learning - A Probabilistic Perspective" uses input and output in a opposite way, is it?

Tags: machine-learning

Chapter 1 of "Machine Learning - A Probabilistic Perspective" by Kevin Patrick Murphy says

> We now consider unsupervised learning, where we are just given output data, without any inputs. The goal is to discover “interesting structure” in the data; this is sometimes called knowledge discovery.

post this [post](https://www.mathworks.com/discovery/unsupervised-learning.html)

> Unsupervised learning is a type of machine learning algorithm used to draw inferences from datasets consisting of input data without labeled responses.

I saw this kind of explanation more times than the one in that book.

It seems that the book uses the terms in a opposite way, where the dataset is viewed as the **output** of some input, is my understanding right?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not the case. I’m almost sure that it’s a typo and it should be changed to:

“We now consider unsupervised learning, where we are just given **input** data, without any **outputs**.”

It can be deduced by looking at the definition of supervised learning from the book:

“In this section, we discuss classification. Here the goal is to learn a mapping from **inputs** x to **outputs** y, where y ∈ {1,...,C}, with C being the number of classes.”

Answer (score 0):

It seems, to me, that you almost have the right picture in your head. The way that I would best describe the differences between ***Unsupervised/Supervised Learning***, would be something like the following:

### 1. **Supervised Learning**

Aims to take a very specific dataset *(usually tailored by the researcher/programmer/whomever for the specific task; also called **Cleaning the Dataset**)* as an input, with which the machine learning model will then perform it's ***Training Process.*** This dataset is also most commonly provided along with an additional set(s) of data which is purposely made by the researcher/programmer/whomever as a source of metadata relating to the input dataset *(such as tag regions for an image dataset, etc.)* **this is the *"Supervised"* part.** The **output** would then be a model which can take data similar to the input and predict with some accuracy the metadata that should be assigned to it. *(In the case of the previous example, this would be providing an image and the model would then output the tags for that image)*

### 2. **Unsupervised Learning**

Is essentially the same principal but with the absence of any specially designed metadata which accompanies the input. ***This approach is referred to as unsupervised, because it does not require a human to assist the model in any way once the input is provided.*** This classification of ML models are widely considered to be a much more challenging problem; as it requires us to understand the principles of what it **really means** to take raw image data as an input *(assuming the same example case of image tagging)* and with nothing else, return all the tags that should be with an image.